# Change colour of + or -

Tags: php, html

I have the below code

```
<?php echo sprintf("%+d",$trend); ?>
```

Which will print out +number, or -number.

How can I change only the colour of the + or - so if I have +20  it will print only the plus in red, and -20, will print only the - in blue?

Comment: Give it a span class or something? And style it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do:

```
$trend = -10;
echo '<span style="color:red">'.(($trend >= 0) ? '+' : '-').'</span>';
echo sprintf("%d",abs($trend));
```

For two colors:

```
$trend = -10;
$color1 = 'red';
$color2 = 'blue';
echo '<span style="color:'.(($trend >= 0) ? $color1 : $color2).'">'.(($trend >= 0) ? '+' : '-').'</span>';
echo sprintf("%d",abs($trend));
```